# Why doesn't a ben niddah acquire the status of a mamzer?

Tags: halacha, marriage, niddah, mamzer

One who commits incest is punished with [Kares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kareth) (spiritual separation from the divine source), and any product of incest has the status of a [Mamzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamzer).

One who has relations with a [Niddah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niddah) is also punished with Kares, yet the product of such a union does not acquire the status of a Mamzer.

Shouldn't the product of both unions have the same status?

Comment: The form of this question is typical of questions and suggestions in the Talmud. I wonder if it's ever actually asked as such there.

Comment: I think the answer is that usually we have *chayavei kares* -> *ein kidushin tofsin* -> *mamzerus*. But by a nidda, although it is *chayav kares*, it is still *kidushin tofsin*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Gemara says in [Kiddushin](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=68&format=text) that it's derived from a verse "ותהי נדתה עליו" - that even when one is a Nidda, there still is "Haviya" (marriage). Therefore, Kiddushin by a nidda works.

If so, there are no issues of Mamzeirus.

Comment: this drasha is on yevamos 49a/b

Comment: Whence the logical jump from Chalot Kiddushin to lack of Mamzerut?